# Save files into a database

Tags: c#, database

I want to save files into a database in my C# Windows application. What database technology should/could I use?

I want to be able to save files and open saved files with my application.

Comment: How large are your files? What kind of files are they??

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you're dealing with Microsoft SQL Server, there's a really interesting performance comparison done by Microsoft Research:

[To BLOB or not to BLOB](http://research.microsoft.com/apps/pubs/default.aspx?id=64525)

Their conclusion basically is:

- if your files are mostly 256 KB in size or less, store them **inside** the database
- if your files are mostly 1 MB or larger, store them in the file system and only store a reference to them in the database (e.g. using the `FILESTREAM` feature in SQL Server 2008)
- if your files are mostly between those two sizes, it comes down to other factors, like frequency of update, hardware available and so forth

And if you should ever need to store a file larger than 2 GB, storing it in the filesystem is your only choice, really. So that might also be a deciding factor.

Answer (score 3):

Storing *actual* files into the database is probably not the best approach as there's somewhere designed to store files and do it well already, it's called the file system :)

That said, if you can use Sql Server, you could take a look at [FILESTREAM storage](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933993.aspx) as it's a sort-of midpoint between the two.

Comment: And SQL Server 2011 Denali will bring us `FILETABLE` - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff929068%28v=sql.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Most modern databases will allow you to save binary data in them. ie in SQL server you have blob type where you can store any binary data you like.

Answer (score 0):

Look at [this](http://www.dotnetspider.com/resources/454-Open-File-Using-OpenFileDialog-SaveFileDialog.aspx) page. There is a example of open a file and save..

so you can implement your own code for saving it to a database?

if you wanna save text i would recommand to use a SQL server or Oracle database, ive learned to program c# and SQL server but learned the theory of Oracle